# Want to click on first job link in naukri.com for any keyword say java through selenium but it give me error

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I Want to click on first available job link in naukri.com for any keyword say java through selenium but it gives me following error  `java.lang.NullPointerException`

```
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://naukri.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='301018007329']/span[1]/ul/li")).click();
```

Comment: your XPath is wrong because of that you are getting null pointer exception. show your HTML code for more information.

Comment: i have checked the xpath it is correct but still getting null pointer exception

Comment: <div type="tuple" id="301018007329" class="row  " data-url="https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-Software-Engineer-senior-Software-Engineer-Quality-Assurance-Pinnacle-Solutions-Delhi-NCR-Gurgaon-3-to-6-years-301018007329?src=jobsearchDesk&amp;sid=15409906381031&amp;xp=1&amp;px=1"> <span count="1" class="content">  <ul><li title="Software Engineer/senior Software Engineer - Quality Assurance" class="desig">Software Engineer/senior Software Engineer - Quality Assurance</li></ul>

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you are not passing `tagname` in `xpath`.
For example:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='test']")).click();
```

`div` is tagname here but in your code it is missing

Comment: thanks Tim for pointing out , but i have tried again by adding tagname but still not working , in naukri.com application we will not able to perform any action on any object which is present in middle . this is very strange

Comment: can you send me the picture with highlight what element you want to select?

Answer (score 0):

It's xpath issue try with dynamic xpath, 
to create dynamic xpath [click here](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/dynamic-xpath-in-selenium/).